# Restrict quickblox user creation

Tags: quickblox

When a user registers at my website I also need to create a quickblox user. I got this procedure to work:

- Get a session token from API route "api.quickblox.com/session.json". But to do so I need a user. So I use my own login to quickblox dashboard.
- Create the user by hitting API route "/users.json". Fair eanough, it works!

## Questions

- It feels strange using my own dashboard login as the token generator account. Is there not some other way?
- The newly created user can create more users! That is, I created a new token with the details from the just created user, whom in turn was allowed to create further users. This cant be right? What am I doing wrong?
- Quickblox chat example available here: http://quickblox.github.io/quickblox-javascript-sdk/samples/chat/# serves the keys and secret in the open, like this:
  QBApp = {    appId: 46126,    authKey: 'Nyc2fwgg8QeFJpS',    authSecret: SUv3grsaDMx5'}; Is that the way to do it? Then atleast I would like to control the creation of new users..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you doing well !!

For Quickblox must have manage session for each and every users,you have to download and integrate quickblox SDK into your web app.

You have to follow this steps:

1) Create a app on Quickblox and add credentials into your javascript SDK or configure your javascript SDK.

2) Whenever user is logged-in to you app you must have to login quickblox as well and get session for logged-in user.

3) Do whatever operation with user created session like (chat,viedo call, audio call)

4) When user log-out from your, you have to manage like user also logout form quickblox and destroy previously created sessions.

5) When registering new user you have to also register that user into your quickblox app.

this way you have to manage user management.

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To create a user with an arbetary session/token this function can be used (for JS SDK)

```
var params = {login: 'test3', password: '12345678'};
function createUser(params) {
    QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
        QB.users.create(params, function(err, user) {    
            if (user) {
                // user - JS obejct with QB user
                alert("successfully created a user!");
            } else {
                alert("error!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

> "The newly created user can create more users!"

After further research I have concuded this is a part of the design and not to worry about. I will add a job to clean up any users created by spammers.